# Thumbnail (featured image) of next and previous post is not being properly displayed!

Tags: next-post-link, previous-post-link

I'm using this code to display the thumbnail (featured picture) of the previous and next post (a custom post type called Blocks).

(A custom loop)

```
<?php // Create and run custom loop
    $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
    $custom_posts->query('post_type=blocks&location=Front Page&section=Mainbar');
    while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
?>  <div class="block-2 border-top">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php // Display previous and next posts thumbnails     
    ?>  <div class="float-left"> <?php
            $prevPost = get_previous_post();
            $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID);
            previous_post_link('%link', $prevthumbnail);
    ?>  </div>

    <?php // Get thumbnail of next post
    ?>  <div class="float-right"> <?php
            $nextPost = get_next_post();
            $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID);
            next_post_link('%link', $nextthumbnail);
    ?>  </div>
    </div>
```

This is the chronology:

[image]

And this is the output:

```
  <div class="block-2 border-top">
            <h2><a href="http://localhost/wpac/?blocks=mainbar" title="Permalink to Mainbar" rel="bookmark">Mainbar</a></h2>

          <div class="float-left"> <a href="http://localhost/wpac/?blocks=mainbar-left" rel="prev"><img width="160" height="150" src="http://localhost/wpac/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/showcase2.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="showcase2" title="showcase2" /></a>  </div>

          <div class="float-right"> <a href="http://localhost/wpac/?blocks=mainbar-right" rel="next"><img width="160" height="150" src="http://localhost/wpac/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/2974999772_7085da4d347.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="2974999772_7085da4d347" title="2974999772_7085da4d347" /></a> </div>
        </div>

      <div class="block-3 border-top">
            <h2><a href="http://localhost/wpac/?blocks=sidebar" title="Permalink to Sidebar" rel="bookmark">Sidebar</a></h2>
            <a href="http://localhost/wpac/?blocks=sidebar" title="Permalink to Sidebar" rel="bookmark"><img width="160" height="150" src="http://localhost/wpac/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/2974999772_7085da4d3410.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="2974999772_7085da4d3410" title="2974999772_7085da4d3410" /></a>
            <p></p>

            <p></p>
        </div>
```

It doesn't matter in which single post I am. The thumbnails of `Mainbar Left` and `Mainbar Right` are always displayed)

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Full code:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Starkers
 * @since Starkers 3.0
 */

    get_header(); ?>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <div id="content">
        <?php // Create and run custom loop
            $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
            $custom_posts->query('post_type=blocks&location=Work&section=Intro');
            while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
        ?>  <div class="block-1">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php // Create and run custom loop
            $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
            $custom_posts->query('post_type=blocks&location=Work&section=Tagline');
            while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
        ?>  <div class="block-2 padding-top">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

        <?php // Create and run custom loop ?>
            <div class="block-2 border-top">
            <?php // Display the thumbnail of the previous post ?>
                <div class="float-left"> <?php
                    $prevPost = get_previous_post();
                    $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID); ?>
                    <h2><?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous'); ?></h2>
                    <?php previous_post_link('%link', $prevthumbnail); ?>
                </div>

            <?php // Display the thumbnail of the next post ?>
                <div class="float-right"> <?php
                    $nextPost = get_next_post();
                    $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID); ?>
                    <h2><?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next'); ?></h2>
                    <?php next_post_link('%link', $nextthumbnail); ?>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php // Create and run custom loop
            $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
            $custom_posts->query('post_type=blocks&location=Front Page&section=Sidebar');
            while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
        ?>  <div class="block-3 border-top">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Other_Work", true); ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php // Start the main loop
            if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        ?>  <div class="block-4 border-top">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php get_sidebar('secondary'); ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** OK. If you get to keep changing the question, I get to delete what I had written before and start all over again.

To be honest, I'm a bit confused about what you are trying to do. Since this *appears* to be for a single post (based on the comment at the top of your template), it is unclear to me what your first 2 custom loops are meant to accomplish. It *looks* like you are printing out the thumbnails and contents of *all* `blocks` posts that have a location of `Work`, regardless of what single post you are on. If you simply want to show the thumbnail and content for the current, single post, then just do that.

Note: because the custom loop for the `Front Page` posts calls `the_post()`, it is modifying the global `$post`. I don't know if your sidebar code is depending on that being the original post or not, but I stuck in a call to `wp_reset_query()` just in case.

Below is what I *think* you were trying to accomplish, but I could be wrong:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Starkers
 * @since Starkers 3.0
 */

    get_header(); ?>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <div id="content">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="block-1">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="block-2 padding-top">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="block-2 border-top">
            <?php // Display the thumbnail of the previous post ?>
            <div class="float-left"> <?php
                $prevPost = get_previous_post();
                $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID); ?>
                <h2><?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous'); ?></h2>
                <?php previous_post_link('%link', $prevthumbnail); ?>
            </div>

        <?php // Display the thumbnail of the next post ?>
            <div class="float-right"> <?php
                $nextPost = get_next_post();
                $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID); ?>
                <h2><?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next'); ?></h2>
                <?php next_post_link('%link', $nextthumbnail); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>

        <?php // Create and run custom loop
            $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
            $custom_posts->query('post_type=blocks&amp;location=Front Page&amp;section=Sidebar');
            while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
        ?>  <div class="block-3 border-top">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Other_Work", true); ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_query(); // I don't know if this is needed by the sidebar code. If not, you can delete this. ?>
        <?php get_sidebar('secondary'); ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: @Peter Rowell I'm calling `get_previous_post()` and `get_next_post()` outside of any loop.

Comment: @janoChen: See my response above.

Comment: @Peter Rowell But weird for some reason it is working perfectly.

Comment: @janoChen: Then either something was left out of your code snippet, or you got "lucky" and the last value `$post` was set to was what you wanted. If you don't understand *why* it is working "perfectly" then you are simply rolling dice and hoping that things don't change. Depending on unseen, not-understood *global state* is a good way to have your site mysteriously break at sometime in the future when an update to either WP core or a plugin breaks the underlying assumption. I'm not trying to argue with you, but if you don't figure this out, you may very well be unhappy somewhere down the road.

Comment: @Peter Rowell Yeah I know, I will post another question regarding this weird phenomenon. By the way, I posted the full code. (see **EDIT**). I would appreciate if you can tell me why is it working.

Comment: @janoChen: take a look at my completely rewritten answer on this. It's the best I have for now. It's a beautiful, sunny 68° outside and my wife says we are going to the beach.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're setting up 2 loops when you don't need to. If you're in a template that's displaying a 'blocks' post (e.g.  single-blocks.php), then simply use the get_previous_post and get_next_post functions.

Something like:

```
<?php 
    the_post();
?><div class="float-left"> <?php
        $prevPost = get_previous_post();
        $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID);
        previous_post_link('%link',''.$prevthumbnail.'');
?>  </div>

 <div class="float-right"> <?php
        $nextPost = get_next_post();
        $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID);
        next_post_link('%link',''.$nextthumbnail.'');
?>  </div>
```

Just noticed you're outside of the loop, in which case, set up your query so it only returns one post. Adding the post ID in to the WP_Query arguments.

Comment: I updated the code, and now I have another problem. Please check the question again.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this:

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

placed here:

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

    <?php // Display post thumbnail
```